# How to make two way-databinding using EF in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am very new at coding. Now I am going to tell you about my current situation and where I wanna go. Hope you will help.

I am using EF5.0 database first approach and I want to be able to use gridviews for listing and updating the database values.

Currently I am binding my data like this:

```
  pehlivan_kabametrajEntities ctx = new pehlivan_kabametrajEntities();
        var result = from k in ctx.Kolons
                     select k;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

This code lists my data perfectly. However it is wrong or not enough for my needs. Because I want to be able to edit my data right on the gridview. Please tell me what is wrong and what should I do. At least links of some documents that will reach me to the destination point I desire would be great. 
Thx.

Comment: What are you having issues with? 1) After populating the gridview being able to edit the data on the page? or 2) Getting the edited data off the page and back into the database?

Comment: Both of them actually (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind to query result you are using only one-way data binding. You need to have `IBindingList` to get two way data binding. Try this:

```
 ctx.Kolons.Load();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ctx.Kolons.Local.ToBindingList();
```

If it doesn't work try to use `BindingSource`:

```
 ctx.Kolons.Load();
 gridBindingSource.DataSource = ctx.Kolons.Local.ToBindingList();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = gridSource;
```

Comment: It says there is no definition for .Load() or .ToBindingList(). I am using VS2012 could this method be changed?

Comment: I thought you are using EF5 which would mean DbContext API but it looks you are using just .NET 4.5 and old ObjectContext API.

Comment: Actually I don't know what did I do. I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project using database first approach and it created my code. I guess I need to start over learning this topic. Can you suggest a tutorial or something to learn things better?

Comment: Is your project targeted to .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes it is targeted to .NET 4.5

Comment: I realised that I can use .load in my class file but not in the form codes.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Why do you use context.Entity.Load, and ...Local.ToBindingList()? I mean what is the purpouse of "Local" in this case?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - is there a way to use Local.ToBindingList() with derived classes? here is my problem... can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990553/binding-datagridview-to-database-with-ef5-classes-not-sending-changes-to-databas