# Binding DataGridView to database with EF5 classes not sending changes to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 + .NET 4.5

I have created database using EF Model first approach and I want to bind `DataGridView` to database using EF classes so that any changes to database or in the `DataGridView` are synchronized automatically.

**This is my code:**

```
//form level fields
private BindingList<Product> _products;
private BindingSource _productSource = new BindingSource(); 

... in the form load event
//load the data from database using EF classes
var tmp = _context.BaseCategorySet.OfType<Product>().ToList();

//converting to IBindingList
_products = new BindingList<Product>(tmp);
_products.AllowEdit = true;
_products.AllowNew = true;

_productSource.DataSource = _products; 

//setting GridControl's data source
ProductGrid.DataSource = _productSource;
```

I can add new rows or change data, but those changes are not sent to the database - what am I missing?

**Additional things I did in hope to find a solution...**

1) I added a Save button to call updating the grid control's data to database explicitly, with code:

```
_productSource.EndEdit();
_context.SaveChanges();
```

->this did not result in storing the new record into the database

2) I added a code to add new records with a bunch of controls for individual record properties (Textboxes, DatePickers)

```
var x = _context.BaseCategorySet.Create<Product>();
//settting all the x properties with values
//that are set in aforementioned individual controls

_context.BaseCategorySet.Add(x);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

-->when I add new records using this technique - it IS stored in the database, but once more a strange behavior - this new record is not automatically loaded in the grid control (but should be, since I am databinding grid to the corresponding EF DbSet...)

And one more strangeness - updates that I have made in the `DataGridView` control to the records that were loaded to database - those updates ARE sent to database...

3) I switched from DevExpress `XtraGrid` to stadard `DataGridView` control, but that did not help...

I have searched through tons of topics regarding EF databinding with no success...

Don't know if this matters, but I am using inheritance in my Entity model: `Product` derives from `UnifOfSales` and `UnitOfSales` derives from `BaseCategory` class.

**One more thing i tried**

I tried the (..).Local.ToBindingList that was suggested by Ladislav Mrnka in this post
[How to make two way-databinding using EF in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736958/how-to-make-two-way-databinding-using-ef-in-winforms)

well it did send changes back to the database, but the changes were stored only in the base class table (BaseCategory), but there is a table for derived class as well. This is the code i used for binding

```
_context.BaseCategorySet.OfType<Product>.Load(); 
//i tried to use derived class with OfType<Product> to ensure that compiler
//knows that this is instance of derived class (Product), 
//not the base class BaseCategory, 
//but I can not get "Local" working with OfType...
ProductGridView.DataSource = _context.BaseCategorySet.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: Do you call a _context.SaveChanges overload somewhere?

Comment: No i don't, as far as i understand this method is from DbContext class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the solution!

I had to add DbSet Products in DbContext class for EF model derived class (Product, derived from BaseCategory class)

After this I could use

```
ProductGridView.DataSource=_context.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
```