# Binding to allow CRUD operations on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am researching the Entity Framework and have a reasonable understanding of its operations however I am running into some issues when binding Entities to a DataGridView Control within Winforms.

The problem I am facing is that there appears to be a disconnect between Data Entity and the Control `DataSource`.

I am setting the `DataSource` of the DataGridView using LINQ to Entities (this is performed in the Form Load event):

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();
FormGrid.DataSource = context.USER_LIST
    .Where(x => x.USER_ID > 1)
    .ToList()
```

This would return, say, 5 rows in the DataGridView; the columns in the DataGridView have been added with a `DataPropertyName` which matches the property of the object that I want to show in the grid, since in this instance the grid is a list of USER_LIST objects but could be any sort of list of objects from a `DbSet<T>` in the Entity Model.

When adding a new row to the grid, I first create a new USER_LIST object with the default values required due to the database table 'AllowNull = false' columns:

```
USER_LIST NewUser = new USER_LIST() { USER_ID = FGetNextID("USER"), PASSWORD = "p", USER_NAME = "NewUser" };
```

However, I am running into issues when trying to add this object: adding it to the data in a new row within the DataGridView does not add it to the `context.USER_LIST` collection and adding it directly to `context.USER_LIST` does not add a new row within the DataGridView, making me think I am binding the data to the DataGridView incorrectly.

I want to be able to instantiate a new Entity Object and then add this to the DbSet, which will then be reflected by a new row being added in the DataGridView control. Then, when any changes are made to any of the other objects through the DataGridView and `context.SaveChanges()` is called, these changes are confirmed.

Comment: You need *Two-Way Data Binding.*  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12736958

Comment: This certainly allows the Two-Way Data Binding but as this returns all of the items in USER_LIST as objects, it does not then allow filtering on the list of objects which gets bound to the DataSource. I will investigate how to filter the DataSource separately and report back with what I find although if you've any ideas on that front I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Having looked into this further, it turns out that the solution was actually embarrassingly simple; calling Load() on the DbSet will load everything back but I didn't realise I could execute LINQ statements before calling Load() to achieve the same results; doing this allowed met to retrieve an initial dataset which did not represent all records in the table but still allows 2-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure how to mark a comment as the accepted answer I've answered it here to try and close it off.

Following the link suggested by [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey), I have implemented the following which satisfies both the requirement to establish 2-way data binding and also excludes the records that I do not want included in the grid data:

```
context.USER_LIST
       .Where(x => x.USER_ID > 1)
       .Load();
FormGrid.DataSource = context.USER_LIST.Local.ToBindingList();
```